# How can I treat LaTeX quotes as a text object?

Tags: cursor-motions, filetype-tex, custom-text-object

Quotation marks in LaTeX are different than in normal text, in that they're formatted ``` ``like this'' ``` (or `` `like this' `` for single quotes). This makes it difficult to navigate through them in Vim.

I usually use something like `` T`ct' `` (backwards until `` ` ``, change until `'`). However, this is clunky and unnatural. I would prefer to be able to use something along the lines of `ciq` ("change in quotes"), just like I can do `ciw`, `ca)`, `ci"`, `ca'`, etc.

Is there any way to tell Vim to treat ``` ``LaTeX'' `quotes' ``` as text objects? (As a plus, is there any way to only trigger this while editing a `.tex` file?)

Answer (score 12):

I don't know LaTeX but this seems to work:

```
vnoremap iq :<C-U>silent! normal! t'vT`<CR>
omap iq :normal viq<CR>
```

I based this off the information over here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

You can add support for `aq` as well:

```
vnoremap aq :<C-U>silent! normal! f'vF`<CR>
omap aq :normal vaq<CR>
```

Comment: This works for `iq`, but doesn't seem to work with, for example, `daq`.

Comment: Right. You can make it work with `aq` as well with an additional similar mapping. I edited the answer. I also swapped T` with t' in the mapping so that it searches forward first, which seems more natural to me.

Comment: This works for single quotes, but `daq` on `\`\`foo''` just results in `\`foo'`.

Comment: I don't think this method can work for more than single quotes. You would need to do deeper inspection of the text than the `f` and `t` operators allow, which would require writing a whole function with variables and everything. I don't have time to do so right now.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**: I just discovered the [vim-textobject-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) plugin, which adds the exact functionality you're looking for (in addition to a few other things). From the plugin's README:

Currently supported text objects are:

```
a   i   Description
a\\ i\\ Inline math surrounded by ``\\(`` and ``\\)``.
a$  i$  Inline math surrounded by dollar signs.
aq  iq  Single-quoted text ``\`like this'``.
aQ  iQ  Double-quoted text ``\``like this''``.
ae  ie  Environment ``\begin{...}–\end{...}``
```

So you can use `caq` and the like as you wanted. I tested it, and it works as advertised, but note that it is dependent on the [vim-textobject-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin. Also note *you must make sure that the `textobject-user` plugin loads first*, otherwise things won't work.

---

If you don't want to mess with plugins, however, my original answer remains useful:

Adding these two lines to your `.vimrc` will cover *most* of what you want.

```
onoremap aq :<c-u>normal! F`vf'<cr>
onoremap iq :<c-u>normal! T`vt'<cr>
```

These create new text objects (`aq` and `iq`) which go back to the previous `` ` ``, enter visual selection mode, then select up to the next `'`.

This will work for `ciq`, `caq`, `yiq`, and `diq`. However, `yaq` and `daq` will not yank/delete the outer quotes, so I created another text object, `a"`, to handle that (`i"` is not needed, but I added to keep things consistent:

```
onoremap a" :<c-u>normal! 2F`v2f'<cr>
onoremap i" :<c-u>normal! 2T`v2t'<cr>
```

The major downside here is that this will break normal `ca"`, etc. use. If you preface them with `au FileType tex`, you'll only have that issue in `.tex` files, but it still might occasionally be an annoyance. You could also name the object something like `ad`/`id` ('d' for 'double' quote), but that seemed less intuitive to me (I was aiming for the least difference from normal operation).

The only way I can think of to wrap these up into just two text objects would be to write a function that checks for another quote outside of the first set and set the `aq` text objects to call that.

**Note**: There are a couple other minor issues with these:

1. Yanking might leave your cursor in an unexpected place (this could be fixed by adding using a mark in the commands (e.g. `` ma2F`v2f'<cr>`a ``), just make sure not to use one you frequently use manually)
2. The cursor must be inside the quotes; weird things happen if it is on the quotes.

---

To wrap all of that up, this is what I personally would add to my `.vimrc` for this issue:

```
augroup filetype_latex
    au!
    au FileType tex,plaintex onoremap a' :<c-u>normal! muF`vf'<cr>`u
    au FileType tex,plaintex onoremap i' :<c-u>normal! muT`vt'<cr>`u
    au FileType tex,plaintex onoremap a" :<c-u>normal! mu2F`v2f'<cr>`u
    au FileType tex,plaintex onoremap i" :<c-u>normal! mu2T`v2t'<cr>`u
end augroup
```

As you can see, I opted for breaking normal `ca'`/`ya"`/etc functionality so I wouldn't have to learn new commands for them since I wouldn't be using the normal functionality as much within LaTeX anyways. That's just a personal preference; not hard to switch the object names. I also added in the filetype detection and marks.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but for the benefit of future visitors: I find its easier to change the latex quotes with:

```
\usepackage{csquotes} % change " " into nice double quotes  
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

And then `This thing is "Foobar"!` will work fine in vim and latex.

Answer (score 2):

#### Plugin [`vim-sandwich`](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich/)

Another useful plugin for this is `vim-sandwich` which has defined ft-specific surroundings

- `` l` `` or `l'` for `` `text' ``,
- `l"` for ``` ``text'' ``` and
- textobjects to easily operate on them.

With the default mappings following work

- **textobject:** replace inner text of `` `text' `` with `cisl'` or if auto detection of nearest surrounding is fine `cib` (e.g. cursor on `h` in `` `a (phony) text' `` requires to press `vibibc`). However, you can define following additional textobject `iq` (OP example)

  `omap <unique> iq <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)l'
  xmap <unique> iq <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)l'
  omap <unique> aq <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)l'
  xmap <unique> aq <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)l'
  omap <unique> iQ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)l"
  xmap <unique> iQ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)l"
  omap <unique> aQ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)l"
  xmap <unique> aQ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)l"`

  Now simply pressing `ciq` or `ciQ` works.
- **add** to `text` with `saiwl'` single apostrophes to get `` `text' ``
  The pattern of the command is `sa{motion/textobject}{surrounding}` and means invoke operator `add  surrounding` on `inner word` and surround type is `latex single quote`.
- **delete** with `sdl'` or with `sdb`
- **change** with `srl'l"` or with `srbl"`

It supports

- repeat.vim by [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) or [Kana](https://github.com/kana/vim-repeat)
- [visualrepeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3848) by Ingo Karkat (not supported by vim-surround by Tim Pope).

Answer (score 2):

I spent a bit of time today throwing together some code for this exact purpose, and since the existing answers either use plugins or are slightly fragile, I figured I may as well post it here. To use it, just place the code inside an ftplugin file such as `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`. Key "features":

- Provides `iq`, `aq`, `iQ`, `aQ` text objects (duh).
- No plugins needed; should work even on ancient versions of Vim. [Well, I *could* turn this into a plugin, I suppose; but if you want a plugin solution then others exist, as has been mentioned already.]
- Rigorously differentiates between `iq` and `iQ`, that is to say, `iq` will never select between double quotes.
- Works with edge cases, including if the cursor is on a quote character, or if the line ends with opening quotes / starts with closing quotes. However, it still has some weird behaviour if you have a pair of empty quotes, like ``` ``'' ```. :-(
- If you're not within a block of quotes, this tries its best to intelligently look forward / backwards for quotes. [This might not be perfect, but it does work well for me.]

Finally, I'm not really a Vimscript expert, so refinements / suggestions are more than welcome.

```
" iQ, iq, aQ, aq text objects {{{1
function! s:QuotesTextObj(textobj_type, quote_type) abort
    " textobj_type: 'i' for inner, 'a' for around
    " quote_type: 'q' for single quote (iq/aq), 'Q' for double quotes (iQ/aQ)

    " String comparisons must use ==# to avoid issues with 'ignorecase'!
    let l:start_quote = (a:quote_type ==# 'Q') ? '``' : '\(^\|[^`]\)\zs`\ze\($\|[^`]\)'
    let l:end_quote = (a:quote_type ==# 'Q') ? "''" : '\(^\|[^'']\)\zs''\ze\($\|[^'']\)'
    let l:quote_length = (a:quote_type ==# 'Q') ? 2 : 1

    " First, assume that we're within quotes.
    let l:cursor = getpos('.')
    let l:start_pos = searchpos(l:start_quote, 'bcnW')
    if l:start_pos != [0, 0]
        call setpos('.', [l:cursor[0], l:start_pos[0], l:start_pos[1], 0])
        let l:end_pos = searchpos(l:end_quote, 'cnW')
        " Exit if there are no ending quotes
        if l:end_pos == [0, 0]
            call setpos('.', l:cursor)
            return
        endif
        " Exit if there's literally nothing between the quotes
        if l:start_pos[0] == l:end_pos[0] && l:start_pos[1] + l:quote_length >= l:end_pos[1]
            call setpos('.', l:cursor)
            return
        endif
    endif

    " If we aren't, then try to do intelligent searches
    if l:start_pos == [0, 0] || l:end_pos[0] < l:cursor[1] ||
                \ (l:end_pos[0] == l:cursor[1] && l:end_pos[1] + l:quote_length <= l:cursor[2])
        " Reset cursor
        call setpos('.', l:cursor)
        " Search first in the current line
        let l:start_pos = searchpos(l:start_quote, 'bcnW', line('.'))
        " If couldn't find, try to 'jump ahead'
        if l:start_pos == [0, 0]
            let l:start_pos = searchpos(l:start_quote, 'cnW')
        endif
        " If still couldn't find, try to search in previous lines
        if l:start_pos == [0, 0]
            let l:start_pos = searchpos(l:start_quote, 'bcnW')
        endif
    endif
    " If still couldn't find opening quotes, exit
    if l:start_pos == [0, 0]
        call setpos('.', l:cursor)
        return
    endif

    " Using our knowledge of the starting position, search for the ending
    call setpos('.', [l:cursor[0], l:start_pos[0], l:start_pos[1], 0])
    let l:end_pos = searchpos(l:end_quote, 'cnW')
    if l:end_pos == [0, 0]
        call setpos('.', l:cursor)
        return
    endif

    " Adjust positions according to 'i'/'a' usage
    let l:start_pos = [l:start_pos[0],
                \ l:start_pos[1] + (a:textobj_type == 'i' ? l:quote_length : 0)]
    let l:end_pos = [l:end_pos[0],
                \ l:end_pos[1] + (a:textobj_type == 'i' ? -1 : l:quote_length - 1)]
    " Adjust positions if they overflow/underflow across lines
    if col([l:start_pos[0], '$']) - 1 < l:start_pos[1]
        let l:start_pos = [l:start_pos[0] + 1, 1]
    endif
    if l:end_pos[1] < 1
        let l:end_pos = [l:end_pos[0] - 1, col([l:end_pos[0] - 1, '$']) - 1]
    endif

    " Set marks and enter visual mode
    call setpos("'<", [l:cursor[0], l:start_pos[0], l:start_pos[1], 0])
    call setpos("'>", [l:cursor[0], l:end_pos[0], l:end_pos[1], 0])
    normal! `<v`>
endfunction
xnoremap <buffer><silent> iQ :<C-U>call <SID>QuotesTextObj('i', 'Q')<CR>
xnoremap <buffer><silent> iq :<C-U>call <SID>QuotesTextObj('i', 'q')<CR>
xnoremap <buffer><silent> aQ :<C-U>call <SID>QuotesTextObj('a', 'Q')<CR>
xnoremap <buffer><silent> aq :<C-U>call <SID>QuotesTextObj('a', 'q')<CR>
omap <buffer><silent> iQ :normal viQ<CR>
omap <buffer><silent> iq :normal viq<CR>
omap <buffer><silent> aQ :normal vaQ<CR>
omap <buffer><silent> aq :normal vaq<CR>
```

Comment: Prefer xnoremap over vnoremap unless you need to map select mode. Stylistically, it’s uncommon to compress lines too much with `|` in scripts. You might be interested in `<Cmd>` which is able to run the Ex commands of a mapping without changing modes

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thank you! I'll look into `<Cmd>` when I can. Edited for the others.